# Testing JPA Entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I want to know how to write Junit test for Spring Repository classes.

As example :
class-AccountMoveActionDet

Jpa interface-AccountMoveActionDetlJpaRepository

And I want to test this repository class work or not.Spring Jpa support some methods like

```
List findAll();
deleteAll();
```

I wrote a class just like below:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class AccountTypeMovementJpaRepositoryTest extends AbstractJpaTest {

    @Autowired
    AccountTypeMovementJpaRepository accountTypeMovementJpaRepository;

    @Override
    public void test() {
    executeSqlScript("/fixtures/accountTypeMovementJpa.sql");
    assertEquals("accountTypeMovementJpaRepository Test", accountTypeMovementJpaRepository.findAll().size(),
        JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(getJdbcTemplate(), "COF5REP"));
    }

}
```

> Error creating bean with name
>   'com.gayan.cmp.jparepositories.test.AccountTypeMovementJpaRepositoryTest':

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: @Jens Cant we autowired JpaRepositories?

Comment: Yes of course..

Comment: Then how we test JpaRepositoris?

Comment: using a test db and test data

Comment: 'recently' there's a really useful article available https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-data-jpa-test/

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring-boot 1.4 and above the best [place](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) to start, *Testing the JPA slice* :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void findByUsernameShouldReturnUser() {
        this.entityManager.persist(new User("sboot", "123"));
        User user = this.repository.findByUsername("sboot");

        assertThat(user.getUsername()).isEqualTo("sboot");
        assertThat(user.getVin()).isEqualTo("123");
    }

}
```

Comment: wht do u mean by @DataJpaTest

Comment: i've attached a link

Comment: You should mention, that this code works only for spring-boot 1.4 and above

Comment: Im using boot 1.4.1. but cant put @DataJpaTest annotation :(

Comment: @Gaiya what problem have you faced? have you add `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency?

Comment: This is the thing I want, Im working on spring project in company and Im new to spring.I have to check whether JPArepositories  work or not properly.They said have to user Junit.And I dont know how to do that.I really appreciate if u can help me to this.

If @Autowired annotations works I can resolve problem.its not working after put this.
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)